# Regex to extract function in PLSQL

Tags: regex

I want to extract functions contents from a plsql source file. a typical function looks like this

```
FUNCTION func_name;            // this could be there in the files

FUNCTION func_name
IS
   var_   Varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   InitSecurity('func_name')
   IF xxx THEN
      BEGIN
          xxxxx
      END;
   END IF;
END func_name;
```

The problem I have is that there can be several BEGIN & END nested within the main function. Is there a way to extract this whole function keeping this in mind?

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that the BEGIN/END that you care about are always at the beginning of the line, and none of the others are?

Comment: Are there multiple function source in the same input?

Comment: Yes, there can be many functions in the file. And also my example is a  simplified version. There can be variable declarations between IS & BEGIN at the top of the function. Also as shown in the diagram, IF blocks also have an END (END IF)

Comment: And GreatBigBore, yes they will always be at the start of the line. others BEGIN ENDS will be indented since they are nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume a function's END is always at the beginning of the line without indentation, while all others are indented, this regex will work **if set in multiline mode** (flag `m` with most regex engines). You also need the "dot matches everything" flag (`s`).

```
FUNCTION\s+[a-z0-9_]+\s+IS\s+(.+?)^END
```

The trick here is the `^END`, which tells it to only match an END at the beginning of a line. The `^` anchor has this meaning **only in multiline mode**, so make sure you add the m flag if your regex engine needs it (Ruby's one doesn't, most others do).

To capture definitions and  code separately:

```
FUNCTION\s+[a-z0-9_]+\s+IS\s+(.+?)\s+BEGIN\s+(.+?)^END
```

---

If you always provide the name of the function in the "END" statement, like you did in your edit, then this regexp will work no matter of the indentation. You need the "dot matches everything" flag (`s`).

```
FUNCTION\s+([a-z0-9_]+)\s+IS\s+(.+)\s+END\s+\1\s*;
```

Here I'm using a backreference: `END\s+\1\s*;` will match END, followed by at least one whitespace, followed by the function's name (captured previously), followed by any number of whitespaces and a semicolon.

To capture definitions and code separately:

```
FUNCTION\s+([a-z0-9_]+)\s+IS\s+(.+?)\s+BEGIN\s+(.+)\s+END\s+\1\s*;
```

---

If you can't make assumptions about indentation and if all functions don't have their name in the "END" statement, then I can't think of a regexp that would do the job.

Regular expressions often aren't the right tools when it comes to recursive patterns (well, there's a way in some advanced regexp engines to recurse the whole pattern, but it doesn't work for everything and is pretty hard to use).

So I'd do it by hand instead. Loop through the characters, detect the beginning of the function (you can use one simple regex for that), then increment a counter for each "BEGIN" and decrement it for each "END" (being careful not to decrement with "END IF"). When the counter drops to zero, that's the end of your function.

Comment: If they are always indented, is there a way to extract it? But i want to extract all the functions, the regex you have mentioned will extract it all into one instead of multiple ones

Comment: I edited the answer to add a regex when the indentation is always the same, and another if the function name is always specified in `END`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :) Do you know how I can specify the "Dot matches everything" option in c#? I cant seem to find anything on it

Comment: With the "singleline" option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it seems to work well on most cases but there is one exception. this happens when there is a function header of the same name in the file. I have edited the code above to show an example. when the function header is there your regex returns the start of the function header and ends with the "END function_name" of the actual function

Comment: Ok I managed to resolve that. I realized that the header always has a ; where as the function doesnt. Thanks a lot for your help :)